# How to have a sequence of output using While Loop in Java?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, output

I was confused on how to apply code for while, my input would be;

```
input: 5
```

I was expecting to have this kind of sequence output using while loop;

```
input: 
5
output:
*****
****
***
**
*
```

I applied this code;

```
int input ;
    String output = "*";

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("input:");
    input = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println ("output: ");
    while (input!=0){
        System.out.print (output);
        input--;

    }
```

But the output was;

```
input:
3
output: 
***
```

Comment: Do some research first. This cannot be done using one loop. Use nested loop instead

Comment: Please be feasible

Answer (score 0):

You can Try that code using for loop.you can't achieve this by using one loop.

```
public class TmpTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int input;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        input = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<input;i++){
            for(int j = i; j<input;j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each different value that `input` will have, you need another loop to print the multiple `output` tokens, corresponding to the current value of `input` .

You also need an additional new line each time `input` gets a new value (i.e : once we are about to run a new `for` loop) .

```
    while (input!=0){

        for(int i = 1;i <= input;i++)
        {
            System.out.print(output);
        }

        input--;
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code, it will work for you.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println ("input:");
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        int outerLoopIndex = input; 
        System.out.println ("output: ");
        while (outerLoopIndex > 0) {
        int innerLoopIndex = 1;
            while (innerLoopIndex < (outerLoopIndex + 1)) {
                System.out.print("*");
                innerLoopIndex++;
            }
            outerLoopIndex--;
            System.out.println(" ");
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input:");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int i = n;
    int j = 0;
    while (i != 0) {

        while (j != i) {
            System.out.print("*");
            j++;
        }
        j = 0;
        System.out.println("\n");
        i--;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("input:");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    int j = 0;
    recursive(n, j);
}

public static void recursive(int i, int j) {
    while (i != 0 && j != i) {
        System.out.print("*");
        j++;

    }
    j = 0;
    System.out.println("\n");
    if(i!=0)
    recursive(--i, j);

}
```

Comment: Try  this with single loop ,Using recursive function call logic